# Retrive all server side data in data base inside app

Tags: iphone

I want to Retrive server side all data in my data base inside app and database will be update automatically when server will  data updated please suggest me right idea i am new in objective C.

Comment: use web service to get data from server and save to your app database.

Comment: firstly check data is exist on ur local DB or not then  Remove all data if data is exits then Retrive server side data form web services..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from server, use web service to get data from server and save to your app database.

and use push notification for when data has been changed or updated on server then it notify to app and from app you can update your database by fetching data from server by web service.

Or if you don't want notification then you have to check all time that if data is updated then you have to update in your app database otherwise skip to save.

It is the best solution to use web service to interact with the server.